# How to configure Apache Ambari Email Alerts

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I am using Apache Ambari 2.7.3V. I am trying to configure Email Alerts. I have Followed the Below Link. But I am not getting any alerts To my Gmail. Below are my configurations

https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.4.0/managing-and-monitoring-ambari/content/amb_create_an_alert_notification.html

In Manage Alert Notifications  I have configured All required configurations. like below.

```
Name: amabri Alerts
groups: All
Severity: WARNING, CRITICAL
Description : xxxxxxxx
METHOD: EMAIL
SMTP SERVER: smtp-relay.gmail.com
SMTP PORT : 587
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether your issue has been resolved. But posting for other users' reference.
You need to set the app password to use Gmail SMTP. You have to enable two-step verification to enable the app password as below. In addition to that, the SMTP server for Gmail would be-`smtp.gmail.com`
[image].

If still, you are not getting emails then you can test the python script(from head node) [here](https://dzone.com/articles/customized-alerts-for-hadoop-jobs-using-yarn-rest)
and test the below:

1. Ssh to head node
2. Then edit the file -Sudo vi /etc/ambari-server/conf/log4j.properties
3. Modify - log4j.logger.alerts=INFO,alerts to log4j.logger.alerts=DEBUG,alerts
4. Add below line to Alerts section -
   log4j.logger.org.apache.ambari.server.notifications.dispatchers=DEBUG,alerts
5. Save the file and restart ambari server service using usr/lib/hdinsight-common/scripts/restart_ambari_server.sh
6. Try to stop zookeeper on any one of the node and check for the ambari-server.log and amabri-alerts.log.
7. In /var/log/ambari-server, check ambari-alerts.log and ambari-server.log after an alert was fired.